# Where mahout logs are stored

Tags: hadoop, mahout, hadoop2, mahout-recommender

I'm new to to Mahout. I've run mahout clustering task, but it fails I'm unable get why this task fails, so where are mahout logs stored?

Answer (score 0):

Look here:https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/bin/mahout

```
 # default log directory & file
 if [ "$MAHOUT_LOG_DIR" = "" ]; then
   MAHOUT_LOG_DIR="$MAHOUT_HOME/logs"
 fi
```

Now depends where you have set your `MAHOUT_HOME`